# Server to Server file transfer through wget

Tags: centos, backup, centos6, file-transfer, wget

I have a dedicated server in Germany with 120GB data, since I have bought a new dedicated server in U.S, I would like to transfer all the files to new server through `FTP` connection, to achieve this I'm able using the following `wget` command in my new server:

```
nohup wget -m --user=myusername --password=mypassowrd ftp://ftp.mysite.xyz > wget_backup_transfer_log.log 2>&1 &
```

I would like to know is there any better way to do it and is the above command stable regarding to these huge files data?

Thanks in Advance...

*P.S Both servers running CentOS 6.5*

Answer (score 1):

Using tmux/Screen would be a more preferable way instead of `nohup`. You can always reattach the terminal, in case you loose the connection.

For the file transfer itself I would recommend using **SSH+Rsync**. Rsync can resume files transfers, and it will be encrypted too.

Try something like: `rsync -av --partial  server1:/my/dir  server2:/this/dir`

Comment: Agreed.  As a poor-man's approach ("I don't want to comprehend the `rsync` manual page") a simple `ssh 'tar -cf - -C /path/to/my/site/there . | gzip -c9' | gunzip -c | tar -xf - -C /path/to/my/site/here` would work just OK. One could also plug `pv` after `gunzip -c9` to get a live view of the data transfer.

Comment: @iSun, to be more specific, you can use the oft-overlooked feature of SSH which actually provides you with two streams, input and output, connected to a process (or process pipeline) being run remotely. So my encantation makes SSH spawn a tar+gzip combo remotely and connect its output to the input of the gunzip+untar combo running locally -- streaming the compressed data over the network -- safe and encrypted.